# Is this the most efficent way? Jquery click on an image to change the img src and the text of an H1 and a p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the img src, and the text of an heading 1 (H1) and

via a jquery click event.
Here is the HTML

```
<a href="#AF">
<img id="AF1" src="image_url">
<span class="text-center">Dude 1 AF</span>
</a>
```

So basically when someone clicks on the IMG with the ID AF1, then these HTML properties get changed

```
<img id="AF2_IMG" class="a-profiles-img" src="url_old" />
<h1 id="AF2_H1" class="text-center blue a-profiles-name">old_header</h1>
<p id="AF2_P" class="a-profiles-body">new_body</p>
```

And here is the Jquery that I created:

```
$('#AF1').on({
'click': function(){
$('#AF2_IMG').attr('src','new_image');
        $('#AF2_H1').text('new_image_title')
        $('#AF2_P').text('new_body_text')
    }
});
```

Now this works as intended, but it's a little slow (loading the different image) and I have to repeat this 12 times. I'm asking if there is a more efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: if the image load is slow, have you actually looked at the image file and its size?

Comment: You can pre-load the images before the click event

    `<img src="new_image" style="display:none"/>

    <img id="AF2_IMG" class="a-profiles-img" src="url_old" />`